# How do I enable the uploading of KMZ/KML/GPX files in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm setting up a site in Silverstripe 3 and have come up with a weird issue around uploading KMZ/KML files into the CMS.

The end goal is to allow CMS users to upload multiple KMZ/KML/GPX files to a page. These files will then be displayed as routes on a Google Map.

This is the has_many declaration:

```
static $has_many = array(
  'RouteFiles' => 'File'
);
```

This is the getCMSFields code:

```
$routeFilesField = new UploadField('Route Files', 'Upload GPX/KMZ/KML files for your proposed route.', $this->RouteFiles()); 
$routeFilesField->getValidator()->allowedExtensions = array('kmz', 'kml', 'gpx');
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Map', $routeFilesField);
```

I have added the extensions to the FilesMatch section of the **/assets/.htaccess** file.

When I upload a KMZ or KML file to the CMS I get the following message in the Upload Field:

**File information not found**

What else do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to my `_config.php` has worked for me:

```
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'kmz';
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'kml';
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'gpx';
```

I did not have to do anything else to allow these files types. The upload field worked and linking to the file on the front end worked.

Comment: In SS 3.1, calling `File::$allowed_extensions` throws a fatal error as it is a private property. To get around this, you can use the config system to get the extensions (`$extensions = File::config()->allowed_extensions;`), add your items (`$extensions[] = 'kml';`) and then set the value back (`File::config()->allowed_extensions = $extensions;`).

Comment: Or as you specified [in another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25298213/1676444), you can use the YAML config file to add additional allowed extensions.

Answer (score 0):

this message means the upload to the temporary upload folder failed. you should check for the folder being writable or change it, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir