# Silverstripe 3.1.5 - Upload Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: silverstripe

I need to Upload .svg files. To do that I added 'svg' to my config.yml, to the allowed extensions on upload field an to the .htacces in assets/. Also all my assets directories have CHMOD 777.

The File gets uploaded but not attached. Instead of that I receive this error in my upload field **SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

```
File: 
  allowed_extensions:
    - svg
Image: 
  allowed_extensions:
    - svg



$logo->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg'));


Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:html|htm|xhtml|js|css|bmp|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|pcx|tif|tiff|au|mid|midi|mpa|mp3|ogg|m4a|ra|wma|wav|cda|avi|mpg|mpeg|asf|wmv|m4v|mov|mkv|mp4|ogv|webm|swf|flv|ram|rm|doc|docx|txt|rtf|xls|xlsx|pages|ppt|pptx|pps|csv|cab|arj|tar|zip|zipx|sit|sitx|gz|tgz|bz2|ace|arc|pkg|dmg|hqx|jar|xml|pdf|gpx|kml|svg)$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Silverstripe (3.1) will not allow you to save a *svg* file as an Image data type.
It may be to do with the [PHP GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) (I'm not sure), which the Silverstripe `Image` class uses.

Instead, you can save a *svg* file as a `File` data type.

To do this all you need is to add the *svg* file type to the `File` `allowed_extensions` in your yml config file (as you posted in your questions):

```
File: 
  allowed_extensions:
    - svg
```

In your Page or DataObject class add the `File` relation and set your `UploadField`:

```php
private static $has_one = array(
    'SVGFile' => 'File'
);

public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.SVG', UploadField::create('SVGFile', 'SVG File'));
     
    return $fields;
}
```

In your page template you can use the file URL to load the svg as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a module to have SVG work as images in SilverStripe: https://github.com/micschk/silverstripe-svg-images/

See the README for general pointers on how to set up SVG-as-image if you don't want to require the module.

Answer (score 1):

The problem "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" is caused by an error being returned via HTML instead of a data stream in my experience.  So I'd look at the contents of the network tab response and expect to see a stack trace with an error.