# Treat SVG as an image in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to upload images in Silverstripe and have them treated as images rather than a document link.

I've added SVG to the allowed filetypes and can upload an SVG file but when I hit insert the editor inserts the tag as

```
<a href="/assets/uploads/somefile.svg">somefile.svg</a>
```

I would like to treat SVG as any other image format where inserting will insert the tag as a regular image

```
<img src="/assets/uploads/somefile.svg">
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197661/silverstripe-3-1-5-upload-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token Hopefully there is a better answer now

Comment: I'm using IMagick as the backend rather than GD so GD's lack of SVG support shouldnt be a problem. Even if I manually set the uploaded SVG's class type to Image its not handled like an image by the WYSIWYG - it always just inserts a link to the file rather than an image tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After debugging around [`HtmlEditorField.js`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/javascript/HtmlEditorField.js), I found that the issue for SVGs not displaying was that the "Insert Media" screen's upload field does not consider an SVG as an image. (I originally thought the problem was TinyMCE but that wasn't the case)

I knew that the [`File`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-File.html) class has a static property called [`app_categories`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-File.html#136-160)  which contains things like all the extensions SS thinks are images. By default, SVG is not in this list.

In Silverstripe 3.1, if you specify the following, it will add SVG to the "image" category:

```
$categories = File::config()->app_categories;
$categories['image'][] = 'svg';
File::config()->app_categories = $categories;
```

Alternatively as a [YAML config](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/#configuration-yaml-syntax-and-rules):

```
File:
  app_categories:
    image: 
      - svg
```

That simple change was enough for the file upload on the "Insert Media" screen to correctly treat a SVG as an image which in turn triggered the right entwine function to use the `<img>` tag rather than an anchor.

While this method solves your specific issue, there could be side effects throughout other parts in Silverstripe for adding SVG to the image app category.

One additional thing, I needed to update my `.htaccess` file in my assets folder for it to allow viewing of SVG files otherwise I got a `403 Forbidden` error.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, I needed to also add the 'svg' file type to File::$allowed_extensions as well as File::$app_categories i.e in my YAML config _config.yml

`code`
File:
  allowed_extensions:
    - svg
  app_categories:
    image: 
      - svg
`code`

Also I was returned HTTP 500 with the following error log entry:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getURL() on a non-object in /framework/forms/UploadField.php on line 911

If my relation was to an instance of Image. I needed to relate a File object i.e.
`code`
private static $has_one = array(
  'Image' => 'File'
);
`code`

Comment: @JoeHarvey, were you trying to add an SVG as your image on the `has_one`?

Answer (score 1):

in SS3 just use this in your config.yml:

```
File:
    allowed_extensions:
        - svg
Image:
    allowed_extensions:
        - svg
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a SilverStripe module to do exactly that (treat SVG as image instead of file): https://github.com/micschk/silverstripe-svg-images/

See the README for general pointers on how to set up SVG-as-image if you don't want to require the module.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.